# How can I add a `/` to an attribute I'm binding data to?

Tags: angular

I decided to render my links dynamically on my page and previously the links looked like this

```
<a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActivate="active">Home</a>
```

Now that I'm binding data to them to populate them dynamically the syntax is now

```
<a [attr.routerLink]="link.val" *ngFor="let link of linkData">
    {{link.link}}
</a>
```

I realized the `/` wouldn't save in the firebase database for obvious reasons when I really thought about it.  But now I can't figure out how to get the `/` in there.

I've tried

```
"/link.val"
"/+link.val"
"/++link.val"
"/(link.val)"
"/{link.val}"
"(/)link.val"
"(/)+link.val"
"/[link.val]"
```

as well as a few others I can't think of at the moment and nothing is working. It's possible to do this right?  Without it the link won't work.

Comment: `="'/' + linkVal"`? Otherwise it's not a valid [template expression](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions).

Comment: !!!YES!!! THAT WORKED!!!!... mind putting that as the answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the binding to work you need a valid [template expression](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions). In this case you want to concatenate a literal string with a variable one, so you need:

```
[attr.routerLink]="'/' + link.val"
```